# Spotipy not verifying via Oauth?

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm attempting to write a Python script to create a Spotify playlist via the [Spotipy](http://spotipy.readthedocs.org) application. I've successfully created an application in Spotify's Dev center and input the necessary variables into Spotipy's example (see below).  However, the script is not authorizing properly.  I've tried with and without a server running, but to no avail.  There are similar questions on Stack but they do not offer complete solutions.  Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Here is the message I am receiving via command prompt:

> User authentication requires interaction with your
>     web browser. Once you enter your credentials and
>     give authorization, you will be redirected to
>     a url.  Paste that url you were directed to to
>     complete the authorization.
>
> Please navigate here:
>   https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?scope=user-library-read&redirect_uri=None&response_type=code&client_id=xxxxx
>
> Enter the URL you were redirected to:

And here is the script that's running. It's nearly identical to that example provided by Spotipy, with a change made for setting os variables for my Windows machine.

```
import pprint
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
import requests

clientId = 'client id here'
clientSecret = 'client secret here'
clientRedirect = 'http://localhost:8888/callback'

username = 'username here'
scope='user-library-read'

os.environ["SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID"] = clientId
os.environ["SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET"] = clientSecret
os.environ["POTIPY_REDIRECT_URI"] = clientRedirect

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope)

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
    for item in results['items']:
        track = item['track']
        print track['name'] + ' - ' + track['artists'][0]['name']
else:
    print "Can't get token for", username
```

Comment: You have a typo here: `os.environ["POTIPY_REDIRECT_URI"] = clientRedirect`

Answer (score 0):

The application is asking a URL that should contain a "code" which will then be used to exchange with access_token as mentioned in Step.3 in https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/ and the URL should look like this https://example.com/callback?code=NApCCg..BkWtQ&state=profile%2Factivity. I hope you are entering your credentials properly otherwise you will never get the code to proceed further.

Comment: Is there a way to catch the url without opening a new tab in the browser? To automize the process.

Comment: @mina: Sure, have a look at chapter 6 on this [link](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/spotipy/latest/spotipy.pdf)

Comment: The chapter 6 doesn't help me for the automatization... I still have to copy paste myself the url opened on the browser. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @mina: you can use Client Credentials Flow to retrieve data if you do not want to parse the incoming response. Otherwise your application will need to send an http request by using the data in URL just as you do in your browser.